# how install ubuntu 22.0 LTS on my dell computer

Tags: dell

How install Ubuntu 22.0 LTS on my dell computer OptiPlex-5090 m Because it is not allow to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS to Ubuntu  22.04.1 LTS

Comment: I'm voting to close as "needs details". This question either lacks sufficient details to understand the problem, and/or there has been no research ahead of asking this question. We expect that you search/research before asking. When asking we expect you to share the details of your research and provide details about your attempts so far.  If you need help installing Ubuntu, follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you still need help, reference the tutorial and be clear and detailed about what exactly you need help with.

Comment: install new LTS Ubuntu not allowed on my dell computer

Comment: What does that mean? That could mean a million things. We need details! We can not answer questions and solve problems if we do not understand the exact nature of the problem.  You need to put in a lot more effort to make sure that we know exactly what you're doing and exactly what's wrong. If we have to guess at details, or if they are ambiguous, it may be impossible to answer.  Please read [How to Ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) and this meta question on [how to write better questions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15152).

Comment: You can tell us a lot of what we need by starting the current Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, download [the Ubuntu Forum's `system-info` script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/), run it and let it upload the 'cleaned' result to a pastebin. Then please edit your original question and add a link to that pastebin, and we can learn about your computer.

Comment: When I was run software update, it is show that :The software on this computer is update and also mansion that : however, Ubuntu 22.04.1LTS is now available( you have 20.04), then I push upgrade bottom to start upgrade it. It did not anything to start it

Comment: Reboot and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a lot of people said in the comments, this question needs details. I can't give you a full answer because of the lack of details, but the reason it might not be working is because your computer might not meet the requirements to install 22.04. The requirements are listed at https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-minimum-requirements. If your device does meet the requirements and it still isn't working, then you could try installing 22.04 from a USB stick on your computer. the instructions to do so are listed at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview.